# Creating a file from a file path that can be opened in Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, file, file-transfer

I'm using a class that extends the TransferHandler class to get the path of a file being dropped into the gui. Now I need to take that path and turn it into a file object so I can open it with the opener method that's already been written. I tried just putting the path inside a file object like this:

```
final File file = new File(filePath);
```

It doesn't work though, do I need to do something special to the file path since I'm running the application in Linux? The app needs to be runable in both Linux and Windows, is there a method that would work for both? If not how would I do it for Linux and Windows separately?

Also the error message looks like this:

> ERROR [Thread-4] 09:07:45 01/07/15: failed to open
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: home/ur/Desktop/out.txt
>    (No such file or directory)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:140)
>       at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:72)
>       at com.ur.log.reader.FileSelectionBinder.openFile(FileSelectionBinder.java:208)
>       at com.ur.log.reader.FileSelectionBinder.loadFile(FileSelectionBinder.java:189)
>       at com.ur.log.reader.FileSelectionBinder$DragAndDropDataTransfer$1.run(FileSelectionBinder.java:125)

Comment: Where are you running it from? Have you tried with a slash in front of `home`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be more like `/home/ur/Desktop/out.txt`?  Otherwise you're trying to find the file relative to your execution context

Comment: change filePath to /home/ur/Desktop/out.txt

Comment: I've tried changing it so there is a slash in front of home and it made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the file already exists at this path `filePath`
2. `/home/ur/Desktop/out.txt` should be something like the path in Linux, starting with `/` in case your path is absolute.
3. For Java, every platform is same, you need not to worry about Linux/Windows (except for giving file path).  All methods should work fine in all Platforms though.
4. You can make use of `file.exists()` which will provide boolean return value in order to have your conditions. `true` if file exists & `false` otherwise.

Comment: I just used the cat function in the Linux command terminal on the exact same file path as the one that I'm trying to use in my program and it opened but I can't even get my program to say it exists...

Comment: with regard to the exception you have provided I can only say that your file is not there. Or else you can check the permissions also. Try providing your full code , then I can take a deep look at it then.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific to Linux.

> Java is **platform independent** language and no special case is
>   required.

**Edit :** My bad that I misunderstood it completely. Did you check with the file permissions? Who's the owner of the file etc?

Please do/check the following:

1. Check for the file access permissions
2. Always use absolute path (with '/' in front)
3. For home directory, try using `System.getProperty("user.home")` like -

.

```
File userHomeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")); 

File fileToRead = new File(userHomeDir , "Desktop/out.txt");
```

4. Handle the file access via `if(fileToRead.exists())`

The above should be able to give you a definite solution. Else, you might be over looking something, which I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a new file, the file is on my desktop already I just want to access it using the file path

Comment: "-rw-rw-r-- 1 ur ur       16 Jun 29 03:50 out.txt"  and "-rw-rw-r-- 1 ur ur        0 Jul  1 10:21 check.txt".  I am the only user on this comp and should be the owner of both files, I can access them through a different method in my code so I don't think access restriction is the problem.

Comment: Since, you mentioned that you are able to open files from another method, I'm not sure what's the real problem. I have updated some more changes in the above answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

So I feel silly. Turns out there was just a space at the end on my file path every time I imported it. I had tried putting in a trim statement but then I was a stupid stupid head and didn't set filePath = file.Path.trim(). Sorry for the trouble guys!